# Inserting data into database - Why am I using -1 instead of 0?

Tags: java, sqlite

When inserting data into my database I use -1. Should I not be using 0 indicating if NOTHING is inserted then return false. Just wondering is this the correct way?

Many thanks,

Mark

Routine.java

```
if (routineInserted) {                                                          

Toast.makeText(RoutineEdit.this, "Activity Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

MediaPlayer mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(RoutineEdit.this, R.raw.whoosh);
 mymedia.start();

} else {
```

Database.java

```
    public boolean insertRoutine(int activityImage, String selectedDay, int activitySlot) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn1,selectedDay);                                                  
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn2,activityImage);                                                
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn3,activitySlot);                                                 
    long result = db.insert(RoutineTable, null, contentValues);                                     // The db.insert is responsible for insertion of the data into the database and stores the result of this action (either true or false) in result.

    if(result == -1)                                                                                // if the result is not equal to -1 or data is not successfully inserted it will return FALSE. otherwise TRUE
        return false;
    else
        return true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)).

> Returns long  the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error
>   occurred

So you should use -1.

Well, to elaborate further developers of this API chose -1 as return value for any occurence SQLException.

For more information you should check [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/75c9e4d594daac0a1d40f1d75c7620d4659471a7/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#L1341)

One more thing, You can use one return statement instead of two.

```
    public boolean insertRoutine(int activityImage, String selectedDay, int activitySlot) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(RoutineColumn1,selectedDay);                                                  
        contentValues.put(RoutineColumn2,activityImage);                                                
        contentValues.put(RoutineColumn3,activitySlot);                                                 
        long result = db.insert(RoutineTable, null, contentValues);                                     // The db.insert is responsible for insertion of the data into the database and stores the result of this action (either true or false) in result.

        return (result != -1)
}
```

Comment: What is mean though? Just read through the document and understand that I should use -1 but understand why?